# JIT debugger not opening in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio

When I run a program from the console that crashes on my Windows 10, it doesn't offer me to debug it in a JIT debugger, or anything for that matter. It just crashes silently. Here is a minimal program that I used to test:

```
#include <cstring>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    char buffer[10];    
    strcpy(buffer,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");  
}
```

compiled with `g++ -m32 test.cpp -o test.exe`. When I do the exact same thing in an XP VM, it does offer me to open a JIT debugger. Is it disabled by default in Windows 10? I have Visual Studio 2013 installed by the way.

Comment: there's no JIT debugger in Windows. However if you have Visual Studio installed it'll provide an option to use a debugger whenever any application crashes

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I do, it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting this registry option:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting] "DontShowUI"=dword:00000000